# Power BI - Why are these queries structured so differently?

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm charged with rewriting a report in PowerBI desktop.  The visual is a table with a number of columns dragged into the Values container.  I've emulated the table field for field, but when I look at the query of the original sheet vs the one I've built, the queries are quite different and my version is many times slower to load.  Why is there so much more nesting in mine?

ORIGINAL

```
    // DAX Query
DEFINE
  VAR __DS0FilterTable = 
    FILTER(
      KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('applicant'[Client Name])),
      NOT('applicant'[Client Name] IN {"TEST TEST"})
    )

  VAR __DS0Core = 
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
      ROLLUPADDISSUBTOTAL(
        ROLLUPGROUP(
          'applicant'[Id],
          'applicant'[Client Name],
          'applicant'[Assistance Requested Date],
          'applicant'[physicalZip],
          'applicant'[physicalAddress],
          'PhysicalAddress Lookup'[physCity],
          'assistance'[funding-source],
          'assistance'[app-assistance],
          'assistance'[assistance-type],
          'assistance'[disposition],
          'assistance'[fin-WD-date],
          'assistance'[fin-check],
          'assistance'[fin-date-paid],
          'assistance'[fin-Invoice],
          'applicant'[AMICategory],
          'assistance'[Start of coverage period]
        ), "IsGrandTotalRowTotal"
      ),
      __DS0FilterTable,
      "Sumamount_owed", CALCULATE(SUM('assistance'[amount-owed])),
      "Sumamount_paid", CALCULATE(SUM('assistance'[amount-paid])),
      "Sumnumberinhousehold", CALCULATE(SUM('applicant'[numberinhousehold])),
      "SumTotalMonthlyIncome", CALCULATE(SUM('applicant'[TotalMonthlyIncome]))
    )

  VAR __DS0PrimaryWindowed = 
    TOPN(
      502,
      __DS0Core,
      [IsGrandTotalRowTotal],
      0,
      'assistance'[fin-date-paid],
      0,
      'applicant'[Id],
      1,
      'applicant'[Client Name],
      1,
      'applicant'[Assistance Requested Date],
      1,
      'applicant'[physicalZip],
      1,
      'applicant'[physicalAddress],
      1,
      'PhysicalAddress Lookup'[physCity],
      1,
      'assistance'[funding-source],
      1,
      'assistance'[app-assistance],
      1,
      'assistance'[assistance-type],
      1,
      'assistance'[disposition],
      1,
      'assistance'[fin-WD-date],
      1,
      'assistance'[fin-check],
      1,
      'assistance'[fin-Invoice],
      1,
      'applicant'[AMICategory],
      1,
      'assistance'[Start of coverage period],
      1
    )

EVALUATE
  __DS0PrimaryWindowed

ORDER BY
  [IsGrandTotalRowTotal] DESC,
  'assistance'[fin-date-paid] DESC,
  'applicant'[Id],
  'applicant'[Client Name],
  'applicant'[Assistance Requested Date],
  'applicant'[physicalZip],
  'applicant'[physicalAddress],
  'PhysicalAddress Lookup'[physCity],
  'assistance'[funding-source],
  'assistance'[app-assistance],
  'assistance'[assistance-type],
  'assistance'[disposition],
  'assistance'[fin-WD-date],
  'assistance'[fin-check],
  'assistance'[fin-Invoice],
  'applicant'[AMICategory],
  'assistance'[Start of coverage period]
```

MINE

```
  // DAX Query
DEFINE
  VAR __DS0Core = 
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
      KEEPFILTERS(
        FILTER(
          KEEPFILTERS(
            SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
              ROLLUPADDISSUBTOTAL(
                ROLLUPGROUP(
                  'era-cdbg Applicant'[ApplicantId],
                  'era-cdbg Applicant'[FullName],
                  'era-cdbg Application'[ApplicationDate],
                  'era-cdbg Application'[ApplicantPhysicalZip],
                  'era-cdbg Application'[ApplicantPhysicalAddress1],
                  'era-cdbg Application'[ApplicantPhysicalCity],
                  'era-cdbg Assistance'[FundingSource],
                  'era-cdbg Assistance'[Category],
                  'era-cdbg Assistance'[Disposition],
                  'era-cdbg Assistance'[PaymentSubmittedWD],
                  'era-cdbg Assistance'[CheckNumber],
                  'era-cdbg Assistance'[DatePaid],
                  'era-cdbg Assistance'[FinInvoice],
                  'era-cdbg Application'[AMICategory],
                  'era-cdbg Assistance'[Start of coverage period]
                ), "IsGrandTotalRowTotal"
              ),
              "SumAmountOwed", CALCULATE(SUM('era-cdbg Assistance'[AmountOwed])),
              "SumAmountPaid", CALCULATE(SUM('era-cdbg Assistance'[AmountPaid])),
              "Sumhhm", CALCULATE(SUM('era-cdbg Application'[hhm])),
              "HasDataera_cdbg_Assistance", IGNORE(
                CALCULATE(NOT(ISEMPTY('era-cdbg Assistance')))
              )
            )
          ),
          OR(
            OR(
              NOT(ISBLANK([SumAmountOwed])),
              NOT(ISBLANK([SumAmountPaid]))
            ),
            [HasDataera_cdbg_Assistance]
          )
        )
      ),
      "'era-cdbg Applicant'[ApplicantId]", 'era-cdbg Applicant'[ApplicantId],
      "'era-cdbg Applicant'[FullName]", 'era-cdbg Applicant'[FullName],
      "'era-cdbg Application'[ApplicationDate]", 'era-cdbg Application'[ApplicationDate],
      "'era-cdbg Application'[ApplicantPhysicalZip]", 'era-cdbg Application'[ApplicantPhysicalZip],
      "'era-cdbg Application'[ApplicantPhysicalAddress1]", 'era-cdbg Application'[ApplicantPhysicalAddress1],
      "'era-cdbg Application'[ApplicantPhysicalCity]", 'era-cdbg Application'[ApplicantPhysicalCity],
      "'era-cdbg Assistance'[FundingSource]", 'era-cdbg Assistance'[FundingSource],
      "'era-cdbg Assistance'[Category]", 'era-cdbg Assistance'[Category],
      "'era-cdbg Assistance'[Disposition]", 'era-cdbg Assistance'[Disposition],
      "'era-cdbg Assistance'[PaymentSubmittedWD]", 'era-cdbg Assistance'[PaymentSubmittedWD],
      "'era-cdbg Assistance'[CheckNumber]", 'era-cdbg Assistance'[CheckNumber],
      "'era-cdbg Assistance'[DatePaid]", 'era-cdbg Assistance'[DatePaid],
      "'era-cdbg Assistance'[FinInvoice]", 'era-cdbg Assistance'[FinInvoice],
      "'era-cdbg Application'[AMICategory]", 'era-cdbg Application'[AMICategory],
      "'era-cdbg Assistance'[Start of coverage period]", 'era-cdbg Assistance'[Start of coverage period],
      "IsGrandTotalRowTotal", [IsGrandTotalRowTotal],
      "SumAmountOwed", [SumAmountOwed],
      "SumAmountPaid", [SumAmountPaid],
      "Sumhhm", [Sumhhm]
    )

  VAR __DS0PrimaryWindowed = 
    TOPN(
      502,
      __DS0Core,
      [IsGrandTotalRowTotal],
      0,
      'era-cdbg Applicant'[ApplicantId],
      1,
      'era-cdbg Applicant'[FullName],
      1,
      'era-cdbg Application'[ApplicationDate],
      1,
      'era-cdbg Application'[ApplicantPhysicalZip],
      1,
      'era-cdbg Application'[ApplicantPhysicalAddress1],
      1,
      'era-cdbg Application'[ApplicantPhysicalCity],
      1,
      'era-cdbg Assistance'[FundingSource],
      1,
      'era-cdbg Assistance'[Category],
      1,
      'era-cdbg Assistance'[Disposition],
      1,
      'era-cdbg Assistance'[PaymentSubmittedWD],
      1,
      'era-cdbg Assistance'[CheckNumber],
      1,
      'era-cdbg Assistance'[DatePaid],
      1,
      'era-cdbg Assistance'[FinInvoice],
      1,
      'era-cdbg Application'[AMICategory],
      1,
      'era-cdbg Assistance'[Start of coverage period],
      1
    )

EVALUATE
  __DS0PrimaryWindowed

ORDER BY
  [IsGrandTotalRowTotal] DESC,
  'era-cdbg Applicant'[ApplicantId],
  'era-cdbg Applicant'[FullName],
  'era-cdbg Application'[ApplicationDate],
  'era-cdbg Application'[ApplicantPhysicalZip],
  'era-cdbg Application'[ApplicantPhysicalAddress1],
  'era-cdbg Application'[ApplicantPhysicalCity],
  'era-cdbg Assistance'[FundingSource],
  'era-cdbg Assistance'[Category],
  'era-cdbg Assistance'[Disposition],
  'era-cdbg Assistance'[PaymentSubmittedWD],
  'era-cdbg Assistance'[CheckNumber],
  'era-cdbg Assistance'[DatePaid],
  'era-cdbg Assistance'[FinInvoice],
  'era-cdbg Application'[AMICategory],
  'era-cdbg Assistance'[Start of coverage period]
```

Comment: Hello, Please paste the full code in both screens; so I can tell you something about it.

Comment: @OzanSen I updated the original post with the complete queries. Thanks!

Comment: Questions of such type are not allowed here because there is no proper answer to dax measure optimization questions without an access to report. Especially, it is actual for huge measures like these.